# Why override bootstrap, not work for run method?

Tags: scala, runtime, layer, zio

I'm learning ZIO 2.x, when configuring `Runtime` using `bootstrap` layer, it don't works.

```
object RuntimeCustom extends ZIOAppDefault {

  // It's not work, And I don't know why?
  override val bootstrap = EmailService.live
  
  def run = (for {
    _ <- ZIO.debug("Start...")
    _ <- EmailService.send("God", "Hi")
    _ <- ZIO.debug("End...")
  } yield ())
}
```

Get one error:

```
[error] /Users/changzhi/github-repo/zio-start/src/main/scala/zio/reference/experiment/core/RuntimeCustom.scala:35:7: 
[error] 
[error] ──── ZIO APP ERROR ───────────────────────────────────────────────────
[error] 
[error]  Your effect requires a service that is not in the environment.
[error]  Please provide a layer for the following type:
[error] 
[error]    1. example.EmailService
[error] 
[error]  Call your effect's provide method with the layers you need.
[error]  You can read more about layers and providing services here:
[error]  
[error]    https://zio.dev/next/datatypes/contextual/
[error] 
[error] ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
[error] 
[error]     _ <- EmailService.send("God", "Hi")
[error]       ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

If I replace with `provide`, it works.

```
object RuntimeCustom extends ZIOAppDefault {
  
  def run = (for {
    _ <- ZIO.debug("Start...")
    _ <- EmailService.send("God", "Hi")
    _ <- ZIO.debug("End...")
  } yield ())
    // This can works, have no doubt
    .provide(EmailService.live)
}
```

Full version program is here

```
package example

import zio._
trait EmailService {
  def send(user: String, content: String): Task[Unit]
}
object EmailService {
  def send(user: String, content: String): ZIO[EmailService, Throwable, Unit] =
    ZIO.serviceWithZIO[EmailService](_.send(user, content))

  val live: ZLayer[Any, Nothing, EmailService] = 
    ZLayer.fromZIO( ZIO.succeed(EmailServiceFake()) <* Console.printLine("Init EmailService") ).orDie
}

case class EmailServiceFake() extends EmailService {
  override def send(user: String, content: String): Task[Unit] =
    Console.printLine(s"sending email to $user")
}

object RuntimeCustom extends ZIOAppDefault {

  
  // It's not work, And I don't know why?
  //override val bootstrap = EmailService.live
  
  def run = (for {
    _ <- ZIO.debug("Start...")
    _ <- EmailService.send("God", "Hi")
    _ <- ZIO.debug("End...")
  } yield ())
    // This can works, have no doubt
    .provide(EmailService.live)
}
```

Comment: Mmh this is weird indeed. I tried playing with `ZIOApp` overriding things but still get the same error... I'd ask on the Discord

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ZIOAppDefault` is meant for apps that will not require additional services, the assumption is that they will only "require" the built in services because you have *provided* away your other requirements with the `provide` method.

If you want to use the `bootstrap` method you should instead extend `ZIOApp` and override both the `environmentTag` and `Environment` fields so that the `run` mechanism knows how to construct the final environment.

```
import zio._

object App extends ZIOApp {
  
  // Tell ZIO how the environment is constructed
  override val environmentTag: EnvironmentTag[Environment] = EnvironmentTag[Environment]
  
  // Tell the app which layers will be leftover from the `run`
  override type Environment = FooService
  
  // The app how to construct those remaining layers
  override val bootstrap = FooService.layer
  
  
  val run = FooService.doFoo
  
  
}

class FooService {
  def doFoo: UIO[Unit] = ZIO.unit
}

object FooService {
  val layer = ZLayer.succeed(new FooService)
  
  def doFoo = ZIO.serviceWithZIO[FooService](_.doFoo)
}
```

*Edit*

Using the original example to show that this works:

```
import zio._


trait EmailService {
  def send(user: String, content: String): Task[Unit]
}
object EmailService {
  def send(user: String, content: String): ZIO[EmailService, Throwable, Unit] =
    ZIO.serviceWithZIO[EmailService](_.send(user, content))

  val live: ZLayer[Any, Nothing, EmailService] = 
    ZLayer.fromZIO( ZIO.succeed(EmailServiceFake()) <* Console.printLine("Init EmailService") ).orDie
}

case class EmailServiceFake() extends EmailService {
  override def send(user: String, content: String): Task[Unit] =
    Console.printLine(s"sending email to $user")
}

object RuntimeCustom extends ZIOApp {

  
  // It's not work, And I don't know why?
  override val bootstrap = EmailService.live 
  
  override type Environment = EmailService
  
  override val environmentTag: EnvironmentTag[Environment] = EnvironmentTag[Environment]
  
  
  def run = (for {
    _ <- ZIO.debug("Start...")
    _ <- EmailService.send("God", "Hi")
    _ <- ZIO.debug("End...")
  } yield ())
}
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/02MMaWS2S6Wwe55a24H7Sg

Comment: Did you actually try it with OP's code ? Because I did and have the same error

Comment: @LMeyer did you override the `Environment` and `EnvironmentTag`?

Comment: Great, help me a lot.

Comment: @paulpdaniels Yes https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BVysJtOkSu2tj02ZoeTCcg I get the same error as OP on my end. And if I don't type `bootstrap` explicitely it gets confused with `Found:    (Playground.EmailService.live : 
  zio.ZLayer[Any, Nothing, Playground.EmailService]
)
Required: zio.ZLayer[zio.ZIOAppArgs & zio.Scope,Any,Playground.RuntimeCustom.Environment]`

Comment: Oh actually Scastie is buggy and didn't tell me I had a typo at `Environment`. So I was overriding nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
object YourApp extends ZIOAppDefault {

def run = {
    val app = for {
        _ <- ZIO.debug("Start...")
        _ <- EmailService.send("God", "Hi")
        _ <- ZIO.debug("End...")
    } yield ()

    app.provideLayer(bootstrap)
}

override val bootstrap = {
    //    val confLayer = ZLayer(...getArgs...) construct Layer from getArgs
    //    confLayer >>> EmailService.live
    EmailService.live
}
}
```